# Using $.ajax with InsertionMode.Replace

Tags: jquery, ajax

With MVC5, I'm trying to use $.ajax because I need to replace a partial view on a web page.    Using @Ajax.ActionLink works except I can't figure out how to retrieve input field values when inside of Razor because the @Ajax.ActionLink was substituted for the form post button. In JavaScript, I can get the input field values, but the $.ajax method doesn't seem to allow "InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace" like the @Ajax call does.

My JavaScript looks like this:

```
$("#Filter_Form").submit(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UpdateData",
        data: { "filter": GetParamsToSend() },
        dataType: "text",
        //InsertionMode: InsertionMode.Replace,   Doesn't work in the jQuery $.ajax
        UpdateTargetId: "PersonListDiv"
    });
});

var GetParamsToSend = function() {
    var f1 = $('input[name=SearchType]:checked').val();
    var f2 = "~";
    var f3 = $("#FilterEntry").val();
    var filter = f1.concat(f2.concat(f3));
    return filter;
};
```

This calls the correct controller method with the correct parameter, but I don't know how to make it replace the partial view that I'm dealing with, which should be replace at the location "PersonListDiv".

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#Filter_Form").submit(function (event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UpdateData",
    data: { "filter": GetParamsToSend() },
    dataType: "text",
         success: function (result) {   
               $("#myPopUp").html(result); 
               $("#myPopUp").popup("open");
         },
   });
});
```

You use only UpdateTargetId in `@Ajax.BeginForm()` not in JS code

Comment: Thank you for the example.  I made the changes and it executes, but the form elements just clear and the partial view is not changed.

Comment: Why not link it with a button. Of coarse the from will be cleared and you will have a new page. Instead of using `$("#Filter_Form").submit(function (event)`. Create a link or another button and then try

Comment: I don't mind the form being cleared so that is not a problem.  Not sure what you mean with "link it with a button".  The code above is already linked to the submit button.  I wouldn't mind going the route of using '@Ajax.ActionLink', but I can't seem to get the input values from within the Razor code.  I now that '@Ajax.ActionLink' works because I've tried using it by hard-coding the input values.

Comment: Because when you submit all the form it is supposed to call the `Action` in your controller. Could you put the code of the view.

Comment: When the submit button gets pressed, it first calls the Index() method just like it does when the window initially loads, then the UpdateData controller method is called after, so even though it makes an extra call, I don't see it affecting the end result.  Perhaps I should concentrate on using the Razor call instead of JQuery.

Comment: I am getting you, but I am not sure you can have a result after a post. It is like you send a `Post` after another `Post` and then retrive the result after the page load. What you could do also is to remove your `$("#Filter_Form").submit(function (event)` just put the `$.ajax(...)` in yout `$(document).ready` and see if it calls

Comment: It does call the controller on startup correctly, but then I don't have a link or button. Sorry, I'm I've only been doing web stuff for about 3 weeks. I must link this call to something on the window to invoke it with the parameters coming from the user input.

Comment: I created a button that was not a submit button and then in the document.ready in javascript, I bound your $.ajax solution above to the click event of that button.  That worked wonderfully.  Thank you.

Comment: it worked. amazing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no option called `UpdateTargetId` in `$.ajax`.

Instead you should implement a success handler.

```
success: function(response){
  //do something with the response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replaceWith(result) rather than html(result)

```
$("#Filter_Form").submit(function (event) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "UpdateData",
    data: { "filter": GetParamsToSend() },
    dataType: "text",
         success: function (result) {   
               $("#myPopUp").replaceWith(result); 
               $("#myPopUp").popup("open");
         },
   });
});
```